# add buttons to listview firebase arraylist strings android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new in programing
and this is my java code below 
I want the simplest way to add button to each row of listview and relate it with that row firebase child (like a vote button for example) ...
should I custom simple_list_item_1 ?? or creat a new xml file .. please answer me in detail because like I said I am new in android
tnx for help

```js
public class Main2Activity  extends ListActivity {
    String us , userId  ;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        userId = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() ;
        us =  Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName();

        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "HI "+us,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
        profilePictureView = findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicture);
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(userId);


        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String  value = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    listItems.add(value);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a reference to an built-in XML layout document that is part of the Android OS which containt only one `TextView`, so if you want to add another view (e.g. button) you need to create your own layout.